# How to write a SQL query to find out customers who have purchased at least two times every month of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns order_id, customer_id, order_date and Amount.

[image]

How to find the customers who have ordered at least 2 times each month of the year in SQL (from Jan to Dec)?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: every or each month ..?

Comment: criteria1: customer should have purchased every month from Jan to Dec

Comment: criteria 2: for each month the customer should have transacted at least two times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
select
    order_date_year,
    customer_id
from 
(
    select  
        year(order_date) as order_date_year,
        month(order_date) as order_date_month,
        customer_id,
        count(*) as number_of_orders
    from
        tableName
    group by
        year(order_date),
        month(order_date),
        customer_id
    having
        count(*) >= 2
) as t
group by
    order_date_year,
    customer_id
having
    count(*) = 12
```